# my app deployed on heroku not deploying properly and shows app started to crashed

Tags: heroku, telegram-bot, repo

I asked support but they say :- I could see error pymongo.errors.ConfigurationError: Empty host (or extra comma in host list)., this seems to be an error in you application code. This error typically occurs when there is a problem with the connection configuration for your MongoDB instance. This article is a good read for information regarding this error (here).

Unfortunately, this appears to be an issue that falls outside the nature of the Heroku Support policy. I recommend searching our Help Center or asking the community on Stack Overflow for more answers.

Please help me repo :- https://github.com/MrMKN/PROFESSOR-BOT

How to check mangodb working or not